# Avoid "3D" near = on Exchange 2010

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have an question releated to encoding on Microsoft Exchange servers. I have built an app that is processing messages on Exchange and one of options is to force the encoding always to "US-ASCII".

As long as the mails goes directly through Exchange protocols, there is no problem. I have noticed the issue releated to messages sent by third-party mail clients (e.g. Thunderbird) over SMTP protocol.

Although the charset is visible in source code as US-ASCII I can find "3D" near = character, therefore the source code is corrupted and some parts of message are not displaying correctly (e.g. images).

To resolve this problem I have tried to force 7-bit content transfer encoding, but the is issue still persisting.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dus-ascii"=
>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor=3D"#FFFFFF" text=3D"#000000">
    dsadsadsadsdsdsadasdsadasdsad<b>dsa</b>
  <p style=3D"FONT-FAMILY: Arial" id=3D"c1-id-6">Some signature with image.=
</p><p style=3D"FONT-FAMILY: Arial" id=3D"c1-id-7"><img alt=3D"" src=3D"cid=
:img1.jpg" id=3D"c1-id-8"></p><p style=3D"FONT-FAMILY: Arial" id=3D"c1-id-9=
">&nbsp;</p></body>
</html>
```

As long as the message is processed by my app, the "3D" does not appear, even after changing the charset.

Answer (score 3):

Your choice of content transfer encoding is causing this: `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`

[Quoted printable uses the equals sign as an escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable), so the mail sever has dutifully escaped all the 'raw' equals signs for you.

> Quoted-Printable, or QP encoding, is an encoding using printable ASCII
> characters (alphanumeric and the equals sign "=") to transmit 8-bit
> data over a 7-bit data path or, generally, over a medium which is not
> 8-bit clean.[1] It is defined as a MIME content transfer encoding for
> use in e-mail.
>
> QP works by using the equals sign "=" as an escape character.

If you wanted to properly process this, look for all '=' characters in your *content* (not headers), read the next two characters, and then replace the '=XX' triple with the ascii value of the hex you read. "=3D" replaces to "=" with the above scheme.

For more information on Content-Transfer-Encoding refer to section 5 of [RFC 1341](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1341), and [RFC 1521](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1521) at least; consider reading the RFCs that obsolete the above RFCs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I am unable to modify the content of the message, as the message looks properly when it leaves my app. I have tried to modify the EdgeTransport config file, regarding to this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772436%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx, however as you can see the changes does not affect SMTP messages sent by third-party clients.

Comment: You need to just handle the encoding when you read the message. The behavior you're seeing is correct behavior for servers and clients. You ultimately can't control what encoding messages are sent in, and I don't know if the server you're processing on will transform the message before it hands it to you (I'd guess no, since that'd needlessly alter the message which is a nono), so you just have to perform the transformation yourself.